# $\mathscr{B}$ is a uniformly closed algebra

Tags: real-analysis

The following theorem is from PMA Rudin. I understand that $\mathscr{B}$ is an algebra. But Rudin links to theorem 2.27 for *uniformly closed* and I can't understand how he uses it and I prove this result by myself.

Let $\mathscr{B}$ be the uniform closure of an algebra $\mathscr{A}$of bounded functions. Then $\mathscr{B}$ is a uniformly closed algebra.

**Proof:** We have to prove that $\mathscr{B}$ is uniformly closed.

Let $\{f_n\} \in \mathscr{B}$ with $f_n\to f$ uniformly on $E$. Then for any $n\in \mathbb{N}$ exists $\{f_{n,k}\} \in \mathscr{A}$ such that $f_{n,k}\to f_n$ uniformly on $E$. It's easy to check that for any $n\in \mathbb{N}$ $\exists g_n\in \mathscr{A}$ such that $|g_n(x)-f_n(x)|<\frac{1}{n}$ for any $x\in E$. We prove that $g_n \to f$ uniformly on $E$.

Let $\epsilon >0$ be given. 1)Then $\exists N_1$ such that $n\ge N_1$ implies $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$ for any $x\in E$.

Taking $N_2=\max \{N_1, \left[\frac{1}{\epsilon}\right]+1\}$ then for $n\ge N_2$ we have $$|g_n(x)-f(x)|\leqslant |g_n(x)-f_n(x)|+|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\frac{1}{n}+\epsilon<2\epsilon.$$

Is my proof correct?
By the way can anyone explain how Rudin uses theorem 2.27 please?

I would be grateful for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is correct. Let me just point out how Theorem 2.27 is used.

> Theorem 2.27 (a) in Rudin: If $X$ is a metric space and $E \subset X$, then $\overline E$ is closed.

To use this, let $X$ be the set of all bounded functions $f: S \to \mathbb R$. The uniform metric $d_\infty$ on $X$ is given by 
$$d_\infty (f, g) = \sup_{s\in S} |f(s) - g(s)|.$$
It is easy to check that $d_\infty$ is a metric on $X$. Let $\mathscr{A}$ be a subset of $X$. Then the uniform closure $\mathscr B$ is just $\overline{\mathscr{A}}$, thus Theorem 2.27 (a) says that $\mathscr B$ is uniformly closed.

On the other hand, your proof above actually shows that $\overline{\overline E} = \overline E$ for $E\subset X$.

Remark: We show that $\mathscr B = \overline{\mathscr A}$. Firstly, let $f\in \mathscr B$. Then by definition, there is $f_n \in \mathscr A$ so that $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $S$. That is, for all $\epsilon >0$ there is $N\in \mathbb N$ so that 
$$|f_n(x) - f(x)| <\epsilon$$
for all $x\in S$ and $n\ge N$. The above inequality implies that 
$$d_\infty (f_n, f) = \sup_{x\in S} |f_n(x) - f(x)| \le \epsilon$$
for all $n\ge N$. So $f_n \to f$ in $(X, d_\infty)$ and so $f\in \overline{\mathscr A}$. Doing the reverse direction, one sees that $\overline{\mathscr A} \subset \mathscr B$.

Comment: Dear John! May I ask you one question? By condition $\mathscr{B}$ is uniform closure of $\mathscr{A}$. Why then $\mathscr{B}=\overline{\mathscr{A}}$? I can't show this. It's the only moment that I can't show.

Comment: $X$ is a metric space, so $f\in \mathscr A$ if and only if there is $f_n \in \mathscr A$ so that $d_\infty(f_n, f) \to 0$, that is $f_n \to f$ uniformly. @RFZ (Is that what you are asking?)

Comment: May be you mean "$f\in \mathscr{B}$ if and only if .."?

Comment: I mean $f\in \overline{ \mathscr{A}}$. @RFZ

Comment: I must to prove that $\mathscr{B}=\overline{\mathscr{A}}$. Hence $\mathscr{B}\subset\overline{\mathscr{A}}$ and $\overline{\mathscr{A}}\subset \mathscr{B}$. Right? P.S. I can't understand how you conclude that $\mathscr{B}=\overline{\mathscr{A}}$ from $\mathscr{B}$ - uniform closure of $\mathscr{A}$ :(

Comment: Can you state the definition of "$\mathscr B$ is the uniform closure of $\mathscr A$? @RFZ I will try to write that down rigorously.

Comment: Let $\mathscr{A}$ is an algebra of real function defined on a set $E$. If $\mathscr{B}$ is the set of all functions which are limits of uniformly convergent sequences from $\mathscr{A}$ then $\mathscr{B}$ is called uniform closure of $\mathscr{A}$.

Comment: @RFZ Please see the edit.

Comment: $\overline{\mathscr{A}}={\mathscr{A}}\cup {\mathscr{A}}'$. Right? Sorry but how you conclude that $f\in \overline{\mathscr{A}}$?

Comment: As $f_n \in \mathscr A$ and $f_n \to f$, then $f$ is a limit point of the set $\mathscr A$ @RFZ

Comment: $f$ is a limit point of the set $\mathscr{A}$ if for any $\epsilon>0$ deleted neighborhood $N'_{\epsilon}(f)\cap \mathscr{A}\neq \varnothing$. But in our case every neighborhood has point from $\mathscr{A}$ but what about deleted neighborhood?

Comment: If $\mathscr A\cap B_\epsilon(f)$ is nonempty but $N_\epsilon'(f)\cap \mathscr A$ is empty, this mean $f\in \mathscr A$ and so $f\in \overline{\mathscr A}$.

Comment: @ZFR Please note the answer to this question clarifies why the closure and uniform closure of $\mathscr{A}$ are the same, that is $\bar{\mathscr{A}}=\mathscr{B}$. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3728890/238328